# Set media playback controler data

Tags: javascript, node.js, media-player

How can I customize the currently playing song's title, artist and album cover for the media overlay in my Electron app?

Image of current Windows 10 media playback overlay
[image: mage of current Windows 10 media playback overlay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I just looked back at my own question and googled a bit more and came across the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API) and was able to figure it out.

```js
navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
  title: 'Unforgettable',
  artist: 'Nat King Cole',
  album: 'The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)',
  artwork: [
    { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
  ]
});
```

*Example code from the MDN*

Important thing to note: There has to be a  or  tag somewhere in the code.

---

Here is a working jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/2npwy3br/6/